# the difference between A, B, C, and D - saying it concisely

Tags: between-among

I want to write this sentence in shorter form

> I want to see the differences between the decisions made in scenario
>   A, the decisions made in scenario B, the decisions made in scenario C,
>   the decisions made in scenario D.

How should I write that without losing any meaning?

Thank you

Comment: I want to see the difference between (the decisions made in) the A, B, C, and D scenarios?

Comment: "_I want to see the differences between the decisions made in scenarios A, B, C, and D."_ This preserves the meaning and will be easily understood by any reader.

Comment: @P.E.Dant (+1) is it wrong to put the "scenarios" at the end of the sentence?

Comment: @Cardinal - It's not wrong, but I say it's "clunkier." Just my opinion, though.

Comment: @Cardinal What J.R. said. Most native speakers would write it as in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Not to take away from other suggestions here, but one option would be:

> I want to see the differences between the decisions made in each of the scenarios: A, B, C, and D.

If the list of letters seems too terse, you could list them as "scenario A, scenario B, scenario C and scenario D," but I find that a bit wordy.

As a side point, you might consider using "among" instead of "between", since there are more than two scenarios. Else, you could use a different locution to remove that problem entirely:

> I want to contrast the decisions made in scenarios A through D.

Comment: These would all work, but I'm not sure why you didn't also suggest: _I want to see the differences in the decisions for scenarios A, B, C, and D_, which was my initial thought.

Comment: Why didn't I also suggest that? Well.... it didn't occur to me. Good one. Also bypasses the "between"/"among" issue, which is awkward because "among" is more correct but kind of sounds worse.

Answer (score 0):

I want to see the differences between the decisions made in the following scenarios:

- scenario A
- scenario B
- scenario C
- scenario D

In that case all scenarios look the same

**Another way**

I want to see the distinction between the decisions made with the different scenarios A, B, C, and D.

Comment: I think the OP wants to reword that sentence to a more compact one! Not knowing the difference between those very scenarios!

Answer (score 0):

You could also ask:

> How do the decisions made in scenarios A, B, C, and D differ?

or "differ from one another".